# Swift: How to work with JSON when you don't know the name of the keys or the data type of the values

Tags: json, swift

I am having trouble wrapping my head around how to work with JSON where I will not know the name of the keys, or the data type of the values. Each time I get the data, the JSON will have different keys, and different data types. I have been trying to use generics to perform this action, but am not having much success.

I apologize, if others have already asked this question. I searched, but could not find a good explanation of how to achieve working with dynamic JSON in an SDK.

*edited*
I had some code in my question that was not making much sense, I have removed it since it will probably not help others.

Comment: remove `<T>` from `init<T>`. I'm not sure but if you declare more than 1 of the same placeholder type name inside angle brackets `<T>`, the complier but think that they are of different types.

Comment: If I remove <T> from init function it complains about passing in genericValue: T. New error: Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred

Comment: Maybe you should look into using JSONSerialization to decode your json into a dictionary or similar depending of the structure of your json, example ` let result = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as! [String: Any]`. The advantage is that you can use Any as type for your unknown types.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't know the value types, how many values or the name of the properties the json contains why don't you just parse the json string into a dictionary and then iterate through the keys of this dictionary and look for what you want. Something like this :

```
if let dict = "Your json response".toDictionary(){
            for (key, value) in dict.enumerated(){
                //Do something with key || value
            }
        }

extension String {
    func toDictionary() -> [String: Any]? {
        return try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data(using: .utf8)! , options: []) as? [String: Any]
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, this is super clear. Thanks. I'll work on implementing this today and report back how it goes. :)

Answer (score -1):

Use `Charles Web Debugging Proxy` to capture what you sending as request and what you getting as response , and don't forgot to press `Shift`+`Command`+`P` to enable macOs proxy on it.

Comment: What is this an answer to? What does it have to do with decoding json?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I suggest to use this answer only for capturing what are requests and responses as in the question says  ```I will not know the name of the keys, or the data type of the values.```

Comment: The question is about how to write code to handle json responses, not to visually inspecting them.